# Unity game randomness issue

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development

My unity project with Node server and MongoDB runs well when Windows built is made but it generates issue of randomness i.e. randomly some functions are called and some are not called when trying to run within Unity application.
Windows-Built performance - https://www.loom.com/share/77a4df4affa74bc29fe9e7654d54891a
In-App performance - https://www.loom.com/share/da715961103f47d19309d5ddfc528160

functionality :

1. Movement of x-axis and y-axis (should start when game enter Start_Multiplier phase and stops when game enters Stop_Multiplier phase)
2. Jet destruction, respawning and other functionalities (should respawn at Start_Multiplier and crashes then destroy after 2f time on Stop_Multiplier)
3. Center timer value (Should be "Starting..." at Betting phase, keep incrementing at Start_Multiplier and stop incrementing at Stop_Multiplier).
4. I have tried debugging using Debug.Log() before and after each function call.
5. changing order of functions and nesting functions
6. removing all Coroutines form entire game
7. changing the unity version and updating from Unity 2D project to 2D(URP) project